# Unable to publish existing ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API using VS Tools

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I just started working on AWS Lambda using C# and .NET Core. I'm familiar with ASP.NET Core Web API, and have done few projects in it.

I was able to publish a brand new ASP.NET Core Web API project as server-less application in AWS Lambda using API Gateway proxy and able to access my Web API methods.

Now, I have an existing ASP.NET Core Web API project, which I want to publish as server-less application to AWS Lambda using the API Gateway proxy. I followed the instructions given in the below URL to setup my existing project to publish to AWS Lambda.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploy-an-existing-asp-net-core-web-api-to-aws-lambda/

I'm able to see the publish wizard, and it stats up nut fails with the following trace. Wondering if anyone here could help me understand and fix the issue.

```
.....
... publish: Configuring project completed successfully
... publish: publish: Published to D:\Aditya\Apps\ManzilApp\Server\src\ManzilApp.Server\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.0\publish
... publish: Published 1/1 projects successfully
Flattening platform specific dependencies
... flatten: runtimes/rhel-x64/native/libuv.so
**Unknown error executing AWS Serverless deployment: Could not find a part of the path** 'D:\Aditya\Apps\ManzilApp\Server\src\ManzilApp.Server\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.0\publish\runtimes/rhel-x64/native/libuv.so'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
   at Amazon.Lambda.Tools.LambdaPackager.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<FlattenRuntimeFolder>b__0(String sourceRelativePath)
   at Amazon.Lambda.Tools.LambdaPackager.FlattenRuntimeFolder(IToolLogger logger, String publishLocation, JsonData depsJsonTargetNode)
   at Amazon.Lambda.Tools.LambdaPackager.CreateApplicationBundle(LambdaToolsDefaults defaults, IToolLogger logger, String workingDirectory, String projectLocation, String configuration, String targetFramework, String& publishLocation, String& zipArchivePath)
   at Amazon.Lambda.Tools.Commands.DeployServerlessCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__55.MoveNext()
```

Comment: This looks like a build issue. Could you provide your `.csproj` file for all the projects in your solution. In particular, I'm looking for the section that contains the `TargetFramework`

Comment: What I'm puzzled with is the rhel-x64 runtime being reference somehow. I don't see this line when I publish a brand new ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API project using the same VS publish command. Any thoughts?

Comment: FYI `rhel = Red Hat Enterprise Linux`

Comment: @Svek I have xproj files. The TargetFramework is v4.6.1 in the xproj files. However I'm targeting .NET Core 1.0 from my project.json. Separately, I see a runtimes folder in my publish folder for this existing project. I'm using a library Microsoft JWT Token related library that seems to be adding unix specific packages, related to "System.Security.Cryptography.Csp/4.0.0" package. I'm looking into this further. But any help in meanwhile would be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah. I expected you would say that... Visual Studio doesn't behave well when you try to do things like mix-and-match new and old projects, especially when dealing with .NET Core. You are using VS2017 by now I hope. **If so, let me know... I can put you through some steps to resolve this.**

Comment: @Svek I'm still using VS 2015 Update 3. Please let me know where can I can start looking into to identiy and resolve the issue.

Comment: @Svek I was able to solve the issue. I posted an answer to this question. Thanks for responding quickly to my query.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the AWS Lambda deploy tool working in VS 2015 on my existing ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API project. I had to change the sdk version in global.json file in my source folder (same folder where my .sln file resides). Not sure what is the reason (still would like to understand), but this solved the issue.

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```